# How to get 1-10 numbers in column 1 and so on in laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I am working on a game and I am trying to create a table in which there are `3 rows and 9 columns`. I want to fill only five columns of each row with unique numbers and I am doing this successfully. Now, I just want that in first column only numbers from 1-10 will come and in second from 11-20 and so on till ninth column that will from 81-90.

Here is my code :

```
public function tickets(Request $request)
{
    $numbers = range(1,90);
    shuffle ( $numbers );

    // Each ticket has 3 rows and each row has 4 blank spaces
    $row = [ ["", "", "", ""], ["", "", "", ""], ["", "", "", ""] ];

    // Each row has 5 numbers
    for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($row); $i++) {
        for ($j=0; $j<5; $j++) {
            array_push($row[$i],$numbers[$i*5+$j]);
        }
        // Let's shuffle to maintain randomness
        shuffle($row[$i]);
    }

    $table = "";

    for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($row); $i++) {
        $table .= "<tr>";
        for ($j=0; $j<9; $j++) {
            $img = $row[$i][$j] == "" ? "" : $row[$i][$j];
            $table .= "<td>$img</td>";
        }
        $table .= "</tr>";
    }

    $table = "<table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=10 border=2>$table</table>";

    die($table);
}
```

And my current output is shown like :

```
|    | 46 | 41 |    | 66 | 49 |    |    | 35 | 
| 73 | 33 |    | 85 |    | 11 |    | 18 |    | 
| 26 |    | 76 | 81 |    |    | 61 | 48 |    |
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create so many temporary variables. For each row draw 5 numbers and then generate random number from range depending on the cell.

```
<?php
public
function tickets(Request $request)
{
    $rows = 3;
    $numbers = array_chunk(range(1, 100), 10);
    foreach ($numbers as $index => $key) {
        shuffle($numbers[$index]);
    }
    $mandatoryColumns = range(0, 8);


    $table = "";

    for ($i = 0; $i < $rows; $i++) {
        $table .= "<tr>";
        $allowedCells = range(0, 8);
        shuffle($allowedCells);
        $allowedCells = array_slice($allowedCells, 0, 5);
        if ($i > 1) {
            if (count($mandatoryColumns) > 0) {
                $allowedCells = $mandatoryColumns + $allowedCells;
                $allowedCells = array_slice($allowedCells, 0, 5);
            }
        } else {
            $mandatoryColumns = array_diff($mandatoryColumns, $allowedCells);
        }
        for ($j = 0; $j < 9; $j++) {
            $img = in_array($j, $allowedCells) ? (string)array_pop($numbers[$j]) : "";
            $table .= "<td>$img</td>";
        }
        $table .= "</tr>";
    }

    $table = "<table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=10 border=2>$table</table>";

    die($table);
}
```

Output:

```
<table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=10 border=2>
    <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>13</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>33</td>
        <td>43</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>65</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>27</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>42</td>
        <td>52</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>36</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>53</td>
        <td>61</td>
        <td>78</td>
        <td>86</td>
    </tr> </table>
```

Comment: Sometimes, numbers are repeating

Comment: I've modified answer

Comment: Thankyou, it is really helpful. Can you help little more. Sometimes, some columns left blank, it is possible that no column will left blank.

Comment: So you want to remove empty columns and have less than 9 columns?

Comment: no, columns will remain 9, but each column must contain some values, no column will remain totally blank

Comment: What value you want to include? `0`?

Comment: I mean, all rows should contain 5 values and it is filled in such a way that no column will remain totally blank

Comment: every column must contain atleast one value

Comment: I modified the code, but it's not truly random. There is always chance that one column may be empty with full randomness.